# How can I prove that $2^{2^x}+1$ is always prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers, perfect-powers

So the problem is that I have to prove that $2^y+1$ is prime if and only if $y$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: You can't, because that's not true. You can prove the _"only if"_ part, though.

Comment: Numbers of the form $ F(n)=2^{2^n}+1$ are called Fermat numbers after Pierre de Fermat.. There is no known example  of a prime $F(n)$ for $n\geq 5.$  If $y=ab$ where $a$ is odd and $a\geq 3$ then $2^y+1=(2^b+1)\sum_{j=0}^{a-1}(-1)^j2^{b(a-j-1)}.$.. E.g.  $2^{3b}+1=(2^b+1)(2^{2a}-2^a+1).$

Comment: For another bit of history, it was Euler who first showed (in 1732) that the case of $x=5$ doesn't give a prime number. So this conjecture has been known to be false for about three centuries. (Fermat primes have shown up quite a few times on MSE already, as a [search](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=fermat+primes) of the site shows.)

Comment: Fermat numbers are not all primes! (contrary to believe of Fermat).

Comment: There are at least two other recent versions of this question on the site. Don't have the exact links right now.

Answer (score 11):

But:

- $$2^{2^5}+1=641\cdot6700417\ne\text{prime}$$
- $$2^{2^6}+1=274177\cdot67280421310721\ne\text{prime}$$
- $$2^{2^7}+1=59649589127497217\cdot5704689200685129054721\ne\text{prime}$$
- $$2^{2^8}+1\ne\text{prime}$$
- $$2^{2^9}+1\ne\text{prime}$$
- $$2^{2^{10}}+1\ne\text{prime}$$
- $$2^{2^{11}}+1\ne\text{prime}$$
- $$2^{2^{12}}+1\ne\text{prime}$$
- $$2^{2^{13}}+1\ne\text{prime}$$
- $$2^{2^{14}}+1\ne\text{prime}$$
- $$2^{2^{15}}+1\ne\text{prime}$$
- $$2^{2^{16}}+1\ne\text{prime}$$
- $$2^{2^{17}}+1\ne\text{prime}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Theorem:**
For $a^n+1$ to be prime, where $a>1$, $n$ has to be a power of $2$.

*Proof:*
If $a=1$, then $a^n+1=2$. So take $a>1$. Now if $n$ is a positive integer,
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^kb^{n-1-k}.$$
So if $n=rs$ with $1 \leqslant r < n$, $1 < s \leqslant n$  and $s$ odd, then since $(a-b)\mid(a^{rs}-b^{rs})$ on substituting $b=-1$, since $a>1$, $(a+1)>1$ also and $a^n+1$ is therefore composite. Hence, $n$ must be a power of $2$.

Q.E.D.

The converse, however, does not follow. Here are the first seven Fermat numbers, with their prime factorisations, where $p_{n}=$ $n$th prime number:
\begin{align*}
F_0&=2^{2^0}+1=3=p_{2},\\
F_1&=2^{2^1}+1=5=p_{3},\\
F_2&=2^{2^2}+1=17=p_{7},\\
F_3&=2^{2^3}+1=257=p_{55},\\
F_4&=2^{2^4}+1=65537=p_{6543}\\
F_5&=2^{2^5}+1=4294967297=641\cdot6700417=p_{116}\cdot p_{457523},\\
F_6&=2^{2^6}+1=18446744073709551617=274177\cdot67280421310721\\
&=p_{23974}\cdot p_{2184072078357}.
\end{align*}

Here are some notes on the conditions prime factors of Fermat numbers follow:

Euler proved in 1770 that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then the factors of $a^{2n}+b^{2n}$ are either $2$ or of the form $2^{n+1}k+1$, whilst Lucas, in 1878, proved the prime divisors of $2^{2^n}+1$ must be of the form $2^{n+2}l+1$; we have then $641=2^{5+2}\cdot5+1$ and $6700417=2^{5+2}\cdot52347+1$. Euler was the first in 1732 to show $2^{2^5}+1$ is composite. He showed $5\cdot 2^7\equiv-1\pmod{641}$, so $5^4\cdot2^{28}\equiv 1\pmod{641}$, which as $5^4\equiv-2^2\pmod{641}$, $-2^{32}\equiv 1\pmod{641}$.

Euler proved that any prime factor of a Fermat number is of the form $64k+1$, $641$ being $64\cdot10+1$. Fermat would surely have kicked himself for missing such a small factor, which toppled one of his only mistaken conjectures, that **all** such numbers were prime! Indeed it is believed he may have found the 'factor' but made a mistake in ascertaining its primality as it is known he knew any factors had the form $64k+1$ of Euler.

M. Kraitchik showed the following: Since $641=5^4+2^4=5\cdot2^7+1$, we have
$$2^{28}(5^4+2^4)=5^4\cdot2^{28}+2^{32},$$
$$(5\cdot2^{7}+1)(5\cdot2^{7}-1)(5^2\cdot2^{14}-1)
=(5^2\cdot2^{14}+1)(5^2\cdot2^{14}-1)=5^4\cdot2^{28}-1,$$
hence
$$5^4+2^4\mid 5^4\cdot2^{28}+2^{32}\quad\text{and}\quad 5\cdot2^7+1\mid 5^4\cdot2^{28}-1,$$
and so $641$ will divide the difference which is $F_5$,
$$(5^4\cdot2^{28}+2^{32})-(5^4\cdot2^{28}-1)=2^{32}+1.$$

Except for the first five Fermat numbers, which are prime, no other Fermat number has been found to prime.

Comment: What's that $p_116 * p_457523$? (Sorry, I didn't write it properly.)

Comment: $p_116$ means the 116th prime, etc

Answer (score 1):

We want to prove that if $2^y+1$ is prime $\Rightarrow$ $y=2^k$.
 Let $y$ be odd:
 $2\equiv 2 \pmod 3,\ 2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. So $ 2^y+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3.$
Let $y$ be even:
 $y= 2^kl $ where $l$ is an odd number. Now if $l >1,$
$$2^{2^kl}+1\equiv 2^l 2^{2^k}+1\equiv 1.2+1\equiv0\pmod 3.$$ Therefore $y=2^k$.

Comment: You did not prove an equivalence.

Comment: Oh i see. I wrote $\iff$ when it should be $\Rightarrow$